# JS/Underscore: _.groupBy or _.uniq to get unique/grouped elements of field is existing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js

A mongoDB query gives me a result array like this:

```
var result = [
  {
    _id: 'GrRQ56ZvTGpSajvCr',
    title: 'Element 1'
    meta: {
      groupId: '1'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 'nQs7T5QZcjbyxe6Yh',
    title: 'Element 2'
    meta: {
      groupId: '1'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 'cbDqv6ExZoYJQJLnP',
    title: 'Element 3'
    meta: {
      groupId: '2'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 'v6ExZoYcbDqJQJLnP',
    title: 'Element 4'
    meta: {
      groupId: '2'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 'qbqiEGwsGyprfutZM',
    title: 'Element 5'
    meta: {
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 'rfutZMqbqiEGwsGyp',
    title: 'Element 6'
    meta: {
    }
  }
]
```

Now I need to output each element without a groupID and only a single element for each identical groupId. (I cannot use `distinct` or `aggregate` directly on my mongoDB query, so I have to work with this result)

So I'm thinking of using `_.unique` or `_.groupBy`.

```
const resultGroupBy = _.groupBy(result, function(element) { return element.meta.groupId })
const resultUnique = _.uniq(result, function(item, key, a) { return item.a }) // don't understand the syntax for this :-(
```

But both aren't working as needed.

My result should be:

```
groupedResult.map((element) => {
  console.log(element.title, kindOfCounter)
})

Element 1, 2 // Two elements for group 1
Element 3, 2 // Two elements for group 2
Element 5, 1 // Single element without group
Element 6, 1 // Single element without group
```

Element 2 and Element 4 are removed, as group 1 and group 2 should be represented by only one element, although there are two elements at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I think `_.uniq` should do what you want.

```js
var result = [
  {
    _id: 'GrRQ56ZvTGpSajvCr',
    title: 'Element 1',
    meta: {
      groupId: '1'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 'nQs7T5QZcjbyxe6Yh',
    title: 'Element 2',
    meta: {
      groupId: '1'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 'cbDqv6ExZoYJQJLnP',
    title: 'Element 3',
    meta: {
      groupId: '2'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 'v6ExZoYcbDqJQJLnP',
    title: 'Element 4',
    meta: {
      groupId: '2'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 'qbqiEGwsGyprfutZM',
    title: 'Element 5',
    meta: {
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 'rfutZMqbqiEGwsGyp',
    title: 'Element 6',
    meta: {
    }
  }
];

var resultUniq = _.uniq(result, e => e.meta.groupId);
console.log(resultUniq.map(e => e.title));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

`Element 6` isn't included in the result because it has no `groupId`. You could change the iteratee function so it returns a default value when `e.meta.groupId` is undefined.